# How to save captured Photo in XML-File

Tags: android, xml

I have a `XML` File from where I load different parts in my Activity.

Now I want to "write" the captured Photo inside that `XML` File like:

```
<task_photo> PHOTO </task_photo>
```

I have a method to capture a photo and put it on a `ImageView`.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        try{
            Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.taskPhotoImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

What is the right way to write the Photo as Base64 coded in the `XML` File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following online site:
http://tool.css-js.com/base64.html